C++/cli WinForms в VS Code
Хочу установить WinForms на VS Code, но не могу найти информацию как это сделать.(Именно VS Code, не Visual Studio)

Для начала установите visual studio build tools с поддержкой c++/cli...

C++ и C++/CLI - это два разных языка. WinForms можно использовать только из C++/CLI. Если хотите изучать настоящий C++, то забудьте про WinForms.
